# what is the best way to convert an integer into a bitstring in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to convert an integer into a bit string in C. I have written a function to achieve this (example) & need to know a better solution for it.

eg:

```
char* int_to_bin(int n)
{
    char arr[] = "00000000000000000000000000000000"; // 32 zeros , coz int => 32 bit
    int pos = 0;
    while(n!=0)
    {
       char element = (n%2==0)?'0':'1';
       arr[pos] = element;
       n /= 2;
       pos++;
    }
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char)*(pos+1)); // need to malloc for future use
    for(int i = 0; i<pos; i++) // get the reverse
    {
       *(str+i) = arr[pos-1-i];
    }
    *(str+pos) = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Comment: You could write the array backwards and then just strdup it I guess, but what specifically is wrong with your current solution? What would make another solution better?

Comment: [codereview.se] is a better site to ask for comments on working code.

Comment: Better in terms of space or time? The complexity of your current code is log(n), which is good in terms of time. You can make it more space efficient, by creating dynamic array, and then swapping 1st half of the array with second half. There is no need to create a fixed length array. Try using realloc.

Comment: thank for feedbacks & what is the shortest way to write "char arr[] = "00000000000000000000000000000000"; " (something like: '0'*32) , because it is much lengthy

Comment: What is “better”? Faster in general? Faster on a particular machine? Smaller source code? Smaller executable code? Easier code to understand? Well documented and specified code? Code that supports negative values? For what purpose do you “need” a better solution?

Comment: Your current code does not need to initialize the array at all because it does not use any element of the array before assigning a value to it with `arr[pos] = element;`. So it could just use `char arr[32];` or, better for portability, `char arr[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT];`. (`CHAR_BIT` is defined in `<limits.h>`.)

Comment: thanks @EricPostpischil . in here, 'better' means Smaller source code. & I don't consider negative values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the memory copy and let the compiler unroll the loop by using a fixed number of iterations:

```
char* int_to_bin(unsigned n) {
    unsigned size = sizeof(n) * CHAR_BIT;
    char* str = malloc(size + 1);
    str[size] = 0;
    while(size--) {
        str[size] = '0' + (n & 1);
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return str;
}
```